# UWP Remove ToggleButton mouse over and mouse pressed background

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

UWP: How do I remove the Mouse Over and Mouse Pressed background of a `ToggleButton`?

XAML:

(PS: this works on a `Button`!)

```
    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter 
                            x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                            BorderBrush="Transparent"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                            Foreground="White"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Result (NOTE the black square surrounding and the somewhat darker background in it):

[image]

Another image of the same button but then checked, maybe better to see how horrible it looks.

[image]

Comment: I strongly recommend you to try using the styling of the `ToggleButton` to control its appearance, rather than hard-coded images like this.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299157.aspx

Example below works just fine:

```
        <Style x:Key="NakedToggleButton"  TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedDisabled">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePointerOver">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePressed">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminateDisabled">
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                              ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                              HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                              AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```